# How to make Moodle include user passwords in the e-mails it sends?

Tags: email, csv, passwords, moodle, bulk-load

I'm looking for a way to make Moodle 2.9 include **user passwords** in the introductory **e-mails** it sends upon manual upload of CSV table with new user data.

So far it is sending introductory e-mails with text that is set up in the local_welcome plugin that is configurable via

```
Plugins/Local Plugins/Moodle welcome
```

This text contains fields such as [[username]], [[fullname]] which get replaced by the actual values, but no such field as [[password]].

I have tried including both

```
[[password]]
```

and

```
{$a->newpassword}
```

in the text but neither works, Moodle does not replace these strings with the actual password; these strings are sent verbatim instead. This happens irrespective of whether the passwords are uploaded via the CSV or generated.

So far I had no luck finding a solution to this on the web. The official help page on this function is unfortunately empty:
https://docs.moodle.org/29/en/admin/setting/local_welcome

Strangely enough, when I create just one user by hand in Moodle via

```
Users/Add a new user,
```

the e-mail it sends to the user is not that from plugin local_welcome. A string defined somewhere in the moodle php files is used. This contains string {$a->newpassword} and it works as expected; the user obtains both username and password.

How do I make bulk upload behave similarly? I'm looking for any doable way to make this work. If my question is not clear, please ask in the comments.

Comment: Passwords are not stored anywhere in Moodle (only the hashed version that can be compared when needed). The only way you're going to get an email with the uploaded CSV password in it is to edit the code for the bulk upload tool to generate the welcome message at the same time as the users are generated (or create a new bulk upload tool).

Comment: Passwords may not be stored, but they can be sent after they are generated - this happens when I add just one user. So it seems this feature is already somewhere in the code. I just need to make it work for bulk upload, not merely for one user creation.

Comment: It works fine for upload, if you let Moodle create the password: the user preference 'create_password' is set; Moodle then runs a background task that finds all users with this preference and calls 'setnew_password_and_mail' (which does what you'd expect). If you want it to email uploaded passwords as well, then you will need to edit the code of the bulk upload tool. My point above is that you can't use a separate plugin to email the passwords after the account is created, because they are not stored - you can only do it inside the bulk upload code.

Comment: Thanks for explanation, I understand your point. My problem is that when I finished bulk upload my system did not even run the procedure setnew_password_and_mail. I then removed the local_welcome plugin and now the system does not send any e-mails whatsoever.

Answer (score 3):

Sending plain password over email is not secure that's why Moodle prevent it.While uploading user record you can follow these steps,

enable Generate password and notify user.

or,

set your own password and enable Force password change.

Comment: Thanks for your post. Where can I find this option "Generate password and notify user"? The only related option I can see is "New user password: Create new password if needed" In Users/Upload users.

Comment: So I found the option, but it is only visible on the page for setting up new user, not on the page for bulk upload.

Comment: Yes, but you can change the bulk upload process and update the field in database while creating user through bulk upload.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on configuration of bulk upload

> Password field: (...) If omitted, a password will be generated for
>   each user (during the next Cron job) and welcome e-mails sent out.

https://docs.moodle.org/29/en/Upload_users#Fields_that_can_be_included

Comment: Thanks for your post, but as I wrote above, the e-mail sent out does not contain password no matter the password configuration. A template that is used does not have any password placeholder.

Comment: Only a link for resetting the password is sent. But I do not want users to reset their password. I want them to use the password that was generated for them.

Answer (score 0):

Just udate all existing users with the same password using csv file. Then use Moodle welcome to send bulk email with their different user name using [[username]] and then type the default password you chose in csv. And it is better to force change password after first login